# Selenium ChromeDriver: unable to set user-data-dir

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm setting the user director to be my default User data directory as such (so I don't have to worry about entering passwords to sites and logging in each time):

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"chromedriver")
browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/')
print browser.desired_capabilities
```

Now I would expect my Gmail to come up but it asks me to sign in.

Further, when I print the desired capabilities it appears that the user data directory has NOT been set at all:

> {u'takesScreenshot': True, u'acceptSslCerts': True,
>   u'networkConnectionEnabled': False, u'mobileEmulationEnabled': False,
>   u'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': u'', u'applicationCacheEnabled': False,
>   u'locationContextEnabled': True, u'rotatable': False, u'chrome':
>   {u'chromedriverVersion': u'2.29.461585
>   (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b)', **u'userDataDir':
>   u'/var/folders/2r/twg_2d4j5cnf2d6k1m_mnx4c0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.ihUqp7'}**,
>   u'hasTouchScreen': False, u'platform': u'Mac OS X', u'version':
>   u'70.0.3538.110', u'nativeEvents': True, u'handlesAlerts': True,
>   u'takesHeapSnapshot': True, u'javascriptEnabled': True,
>   u'databaseEnabled': False, u'browserName': u'chrome',
>   u'webStorageEnabled': True, u'browserConnectionEnabled': False,
>   u'cssSelectorsEnabled': True, u'pageLoadStrategy': u'normal'}

I am on the latest version of Selenium (3.141) and ChromeDriver (2.29.461585)

Comment: Yelling at us isn't doing you any favors.

Comment: Not trying to yell - just trying to get some attention to this question so it can be properly answered - it's not going to get answered if it's closed

Comment: You appear to have placed two hyphens in front of `user-data-dir`. These hyphens do not appear in the online examples.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab. I have removed the two hyphens and it doesn't work either. Please reproduce and resolve locally

Comment: You're also expecting `~` to be tilde-expanded. This seems unlikely; shell command line processing probably doesn't happen.

Comment: I've also tried playing with this to no avail. Please reproduce and resolve locally to confirm your answers.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate that your question is not a dup, you need to show your work. Show that you addressed the different approaches that are contained in the dups and how it was that they didn't work (error messages, etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to remove `/Default/` because its not valid directory for `--user-data-dir` it is for `--profile-directory`

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
# or
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=other_profile')
```

Comment: I have found that while opening Chrome via Selenium using the Default profile it crashes a lot (race condition?) - so it's best to just create another profile and point to that