# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities error with ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First, machine and package specs:
I am running:

```
ChromeDriver version 75.0.3770.140
Selenium: version '3.141.0'
WSL (linux subsystem) of windows 10
```

I am trying to run a chromebrowser through selenium. I found: [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is) commands, to use selenium through google chrome.

I have a test directory, with only the chromedriver binary file, and the script, in it. The location of the directory is: /home/kela/test_dir/

I ran the code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


options = Options()
options.binary_location='/home/kela/test_dir/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options,executable_path='/home/kela/test_dir/chromedriver')
```

The output from this code is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

Can anyone explain why I need capabilities when the same script works for others without capabilities? I did try adding:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

but I got the same error. So I'm not sure what capabilities I need to add (considering it works for others without it?)

Edit 1: Addressing DebanjanB's comments below:

1. Chromedriver is in the expected location. I am using windows 10. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674914/google-chrome-path-in-windows-10), the expected location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe; and this is where it is on my machine (I copied and pasted this location from the chrome Properties table).
2. ChromeDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.

[image]

3. I definitely have Google Chrome v75.0 installed (I can see that the Product version 75.0.3770.100)
4. I am running the script as a non-root user, as my bash command line ends with a $ and not  # (i.e kela:~/test_dir$ and not kela:~/test_dir#)

Edit 2: Based on DebanjanB's answer below, I am very close to having it working, but just not quite.

The code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location='/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Produces a dialog box that reads:
`Google Chrome cannot read and write to it's data directory: /tmp/.com/google.Chrom.gyw63s`

So then I double checked my Chrome permissions and I should be able to write to Chrome:
[image]

Also, I can see that /tmp/ has a bunch of .com dirs in it:

```
.com.google.Chrome.4jnWme/ .com.google.Chrome.FdNyKP/ .com.google.Chrome.VAcWMQ/ .com.google.Chrome.ZbkRx0/ .com.google.Chrome.iRrceF/
.com.google.Chrome.A2QHHB/ .com.google.Chrome.G7Y51c/ .com.google.Chrome.WD8BtK/ .com.google.Chrome.cItmhA/ .com.google.Chrome.pm28hN/
```

However, since that seemed to be more of a warning than an error, I clicked 'ok' to close the dialog box, and a new tab does open in the browser; but the URL is just 'data:,'. The same thing happens if I remove the line 'driver.get('http://google.com')' from the script, so I know the warning/issue is with the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options,executable_path='/home/kela/test_dir/chromedriver')
```

For example, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599079/selenium-chromedriver-unable-to-set-user-data-dir), I tried adding:

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```

But the same warning pops up.

Edit 3:

As edit 3 was starting to veer into a different question than specifically being addressed here, I started a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114969/selenium-and-chrome-manifest-file-is-missing-or-unreadable).

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/57092707/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thanks, I've hopefully made it more succint

Comment: Thanks, I agree that there are other questions like this, I tagged one of them in the OP, you can see from my edit above based on DebanjanB's answer that none of the similar questions/suggestions seem to work for my issue and I wasn't sure what to do next except to just ask the community to show my specific issue (not that particular link you suggest though, as it's working with geckodriver/firefox and mine is chromedriver/chrome, although I agree that the solution that I eventually find is probably applicable across different drivers).

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

### binary_location

[binary_location](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.binary_location) set/get(s) the location of the **Chrome** (executable) binary and is defined as:

```
def binary_location(self, value):
    """
    Allows you to set where the chromium binary lives

    :Args:
     - value: path to the Chromium binary
    """
    self._binary_location = value
```

So as per your code trials, `options.binary_location='/home/kela/test_dir/chromedriver'` is incorrect.

---

### Solution

If *Chrome* is installed at the default location, you can safely remove this property. Incase *Chrome* is installed at a customized location you need to use the `options.binary_location` *property* to point to the *Chrome* installation.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)

Effectively, you code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/home/kela/test_dir/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Additionally, ensure the following:

- ChromeDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- As you are using *ChromeDriver v75.0* ensure that you have the recommended version of the *Google Chrome v75.0* as:

  ```
  ---------ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 (2019-04-29)---------
  Supports Chrome version 75
  ```
- Execute the *Selenium Test* as **non-root** user.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of these solutions, I've added edits to the OP, but I don't think they fix the issue in my case.

Comment: @Slowat_Kela Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, i've edited my question above to update status. I am definitely closer, so I appreciate it. Let me know if you think we have now veered off topic from the original question and I should open a new question. I did look into my current issue myself before posting here, but I can't see a specific answer in the context of selenium and python, that would work in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

you are importing the FireFox option not the Chrome Option, you have to make sure that you are importing the correct Option to start the selenium

for your case

change this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
```

to this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: Yeah this is the point of my problem.