# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to start using selenium on my laptop, but i just keep getting into errors, after about 1h I'm done trying to fix it by myself.

```
Selenium version: 3.141.0
chromedriver versoin: 860224
Chrome version: 90.0.4430.11
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
```

I have this following bit of code(which is copied from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092707/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea):

```py
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'/opt/google/chrome-unstable/google-chrome-unstable'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options= options, executable_path= '/home/andrei399/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Can anyone please help me? I've been over a lot of stuff, before i restarted my laptop it said it didn't find any binary file, although the path led straight to the x program, I've tried with chrome (not chrome-unstable), although now that doesn't seem to be the problem anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using webdriver.Chrome function but you have imported firefox options

Change your code to the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'/opt/google/chrome-unstable/google-chrome-unstable'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options= options, executable_path= '/home/andrei399/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're right, i wanted to do it with firefox at first but gecko was not working, thought i'd switch to chrome but totally forgot about changing that.Thank you so much.