# InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use,

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning Selenium. I started with a small project.
I am trying to open a link in customized profile's Chrome. 
But it failed and show the message below:

> InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use,...

I tried many ways but it was not success.

Technology I use: Java, Selenium, ChromeDriver

The links I've already tried:

[How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium)

[Selenium ChromeDriver: unable to set user-data-dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599079/selenium-chromedriver-unable-to-set-user-data-dir)

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/adding-user-data-dir-option-to-chromedriver-makes-it-not-work-and-timeout-only

```java
String path = "D:\\pathtoexe\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("window-size=1024,768");
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 2");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("link_page");
```

> Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}) on port 43394
>      Only local connections are allowed.
>
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir